# Highcharts : Best practise for generate venn diagram

Tags: highcharts, export, venn-diagram

I would to create different venn diagram like that http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/12/35/figure/F1 and use Highchart library (because there is a good exporting option). I found [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/AyqzZ/) but i can't make the ellipses when i have 4 datasets. I think it's at "Maker" level parameters that it's possible to do it. But there is maybe another solution. Please can you give me few leads?

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo:'container',
        type:'scatter'
    },
    title:{
        text:'Chart Title'
    },
    credits:{enabled:false},
    legend:{},
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            shadow:false,
            borderWidth:0,
            marker:{
                symbol:'circle'
            }                            
        }
    },
    xAxis:{
        min:0,
        max:10,
        lineWidth:0,
        gridLineWidth:0,
        title:{text:''},
        labels:{enabled:false}
    },
    yAxis:{
        min:0,
        max:100,
        lineWidth:0,
        gridLineWidth:0,
        title:{text:''},
        labels:{enabled:false}
    },    
    series: [{
        color:'rgba(90,155,212,.5)',
        name:'this thing',
        data: [{
            x:3,
            y:50,
            marker:{
                radius:150,
                fillColor:'rgba(90,155,212,.5)',
                lineColor:'rgba(90,155,212,.75)',
                lineWidth:1,
                states:{
                    hover:{
                        radius:150
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    },{
       color:'rgba(241,90,96,.5)',
       name:'that thing',
       data: [{
           x:6,
           y:60,
           marker:{
               radius:125,
               fillColor:'rgba(241,90,96,.5)',
               lineColor:'rgba(241,90,96,.75)',
               lineWidth:1,
               states:{
                   hover:{
                       radius:125
                   }
               }
           }
       }]
    },{
       color:'rgba(250,250,91,.5)',
       name:'the other thing',
       data: [{
           x:5,
           y:25,
           marker:{
               radius:50,
               fillColor:'rgba(250,250,91,.5)',
               lineColor:'rgba(250,250,91,.75)',
               lineWidth:1,
               states:{
                   hover:{
                       radius:50
                   }
               }
           }
       }]
    }]
});
```

Comment: There are four Venn diagrams in that first link, which one would you like to be able to make?  You mention ellipses but the jsfiddle example only has circles (which technically are ellipses, but then I would think you'd explicitly say "circles").  Do you simply want to be able to add a fourth circle to the jsfiddle example?  If so, that's easy, just add to the existing example like so: http://jsfiddle.net/AyqzZ/24/.  By "Maker" do you mean "marker"?  Also if you raise an issue on their Github page, they're very fast and helpful at responding.

Comment: I would like to be able to make a four-set Venn diagram with the ellipses. I can not change the circle to ellipses.

Comment: Have you since tried something?

Comment: I emulated venn diagram as : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50642260/2683452
PS: credit goes to : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20193431/2683452

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built in to draw elipse marker types.

In order to achieve that type of diagram in Highcharts, you'll have to draw the ellipses yourself.

Take a look at this demo:

http://highcharts.com/demo/renderer

and at the docs for the Renderer function:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer